# MongoDB - How to design my collections? Do I need nested collections?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help with designing my Mongo database (I'm new with MongoDB).
This is my current status
[image: currstatus]

This keys and vals are for ONE feature, and I want `Features_Collection` to contain a lot of features (For simplicity - 1000).

### First solution

Creating 1000 Collections. Every collection will have it's name `Feature1_Collection`, `Feature2_Collection`, etc...,

And the values will be like in the screen shot - `Xs` and `Ys`, and I could search for `Xs` in `O(Log(N))`.

Is this solution good? Is it normal to work with 1000 Collections?

### Second solution

I've tried creating key of feature name, and insert inside an array of dicts of the keys and values 
`(Array: [{"x": 0.659, "y":".."},{"x":0.6611613,"y":..} )`

But I think that in this way I won't enjoy the advantages of searching in `O(1)` which is imported for me in this project.

Edit: For clarity:
O(Log(N)) - Complexity of searching. Xs: x values: [0.659, 0.6611613...] Ys: y values: [... , ...]

Comment: Hey, I tried to fix some formatting issue with your question, but there are still some English issue that don't help to understand your question (especially for non English natives like me). Can you please try to fix that? +What do you means by `O(1)`, `Xs` and `Ys`?

Comment: How about solution 3, a collection which holds: `featureX,x,y`

Comment: @Wolph 
I think I your solution is the best. 
One question: 
If I define _id to be (featureX + x), do I have to create index in order to search efficiently? Or the _id will be enough? Thanks

Comment: Another question is... how likely is it that you will query all (or most) values for a certain feature at the same time? If you do query them at the same time than solution 2 could still be a good idea.

Comment: For each new item I will get, I will compute his 'x' field for 'featureX', and will return the 'y' field for the closest 'x' I have in the DB.
For example, I have {x=0.6, y=0.2} {x=0.7, y=0.3} in the DB. The user gives me item with x=0.63 (It is given), I need to return 0.2. (Because x=0.6 is the closest to 0.63) 
I made the _id to be "FeatureX:X" so they are unique